# How to set agents location using for loop in Java

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using this code for assigning dfferent node to different agents

```
int[] node = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
for (int i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    if(agent.participant == i + 1){
    agent.setLocation(node[i]);
    }
}
```

The only problem is  `setLocation()`  function only accept point arguments not integer.

I also try to make the list of points but it does not work. Let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Of course this won't work... You are saying setLocation of agent to 1? How would AnyLogic understand an integer as a Location? You array should consist of nodes for this to work... Your code has no mention of any node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Emile:

```
Node[] nodes = {node0, node1, ...};
int counter=0;
for (Node currNode : nodes) {
    if(agent.participant == counter + 1){
        agent.setLocation(nodes [i]);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

You need to understand function arguments. `setLocation(...)` cannot work with an `int`, it needs something that is an actual location. Check the API, code-complete help, etc